# Directive which switches from a Select to an Input - watch not firing

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm trying to create a directive which has a select (dropdown), and when you select one of the options, it will change into an input instead.

the dropdown has values 1-12, and one value which is 'more...', when the user selects 'more...' the select should change to an input.

The problem is the change never occurs.

I have my code in a plunker here for people to play with: http://plnkr.co/edit/3SyFIYULDHMKgkJmtPtP?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] ); // create app

app.controller( 'myCtrl', [ '$scope', function ( $scope ){ // simple controller
  $scope.value = '0';
  $scope.$watch('value', function(newValue, oldValue){
      console.log('watch fired in controller', newValue); // write the new value on change
  });
}]); 

app.directive('selectSwitch', function () { // the directive
  return {
  restrict: 'E', 
  template: '<div>'+  // template should know to switch between input and select
        '<input ng-model="myModel" ng-if="showInput" />'+ 
        '<select ng-model="myModel" ng-if="!showInput">'+
          '<option ng-repeat="value in selectSwitchValues" value="{{value}}">{{value}}<option>'+
        '<select>'+
      '<div>',
  scope: { 
      myModel: '=', // tie it to my model
  },
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.selectSwitchValues = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','more...']; // values for select
    scope.showInput = false; 
    scope.$watch('myModel', function(newValue, oldValue){ // watch for changes in directive
      console.log('watch fired in directive');
      if(scope.myModel === "more..."){
        console.log("more");
        scope.showInput = true;
      }
      else {
        console.log(scope.myModel);
      }
    });
  }
  };
});
```

I also tried it with ng-switch but no luck either:

```
template: '<div ng-switch on="showInput">'+
    '<input ng-model="myModel" ng-switch-when="showInput">'+ 
    '<select ng-model="myModel" ng-switch-default>'+
        '<option ng-repeat="value in selectSwitchValues" value="{{value}}">{{value}}<option>'+
    '<select>'+
    '<div>',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here...

1) For the value of `myModel` to change properly, use `ngOptions` instead of `ngRepeat`.

2) `ngIf` (and `ngSwitch`) create a new child scope, so the `myModel` was not updating properly. Use `ngShow` and `ngHide` instead...

```
template: '<div>'+
    '<input ng-model="myModel" ng-show="showInput">'+  
      '<select ng-model="myModel" ng-hide="showInput" ng-options="value for value in selectSwitchValues">'+
      '<select>'+
  '<div>',
```

3) `value` needs to be passed into the directive...

```
<select-switch my-model='value'></select-switch>
```

[**Updated Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VJsEtn4eYyzoInov7QKR?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

As @Anthony already pointed out due to usage of ng-if new child scope was created, so mymodel was not updating.
And if you want to use ng-if for compilation all the time for specific purposes you can use

```
$parent.myModel
```

Template as follows

```
template: '<div>'+
    '<input ng-model="$parent.myModel" ng-if="showInput">'+ 
      '<select ng-model="$parent.myModel" ng-if="!showInput" ng-options="value for value in selectSwitchValues">'+
      '<select>'+
  '<div>',
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9CSmoichRIEf1Wa4c1Q7?p=preview)